# Navigation Drawer Above the StatusBar should be Opaque

Tags: android, navigation, styles, statusbar

I am able to Display the Navigation Drawer transparent and Translucent above the Status Bar but i want, the Status bar should be Completely Opaque and the background should be Completely white of the Navigation Drawer Header .I have not used the Default Navigation Drawer Activity and please don't suggest me to use Default Navigation Drawer Activity.

**styles**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

**styles-v21**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>


</resources>
```

**home**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#3EB7C2"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/logoheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.3"

                android:background="@mipmap/nav_header_logo" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

 </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**when   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"**

[image]

**when   android:fitsSystemWindows="false"**

[image]

**want to achieve something like below as background color white**

[image]

> Can the Navigation Drawer be completely Opqaue above the status bar?

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` make it false

Comment: @Ibrahim you can see the images which i get.But i want it completely opaque.i.e means status bar shouldnot be visible on the overlap section of the navigation drawer and Status Bar